# CMFEditions Comparison between Revisions for Custom Type

Tags: plone, archetypes

With Type Settings for News Item set to "Automatic Versioning":

[image: News Item is set Automatic Versioning by default]

I can see the (comparable) History view:

[image: News Item saves Version History that can be Viewed and Compared]

and the inline differences:

[image: News Item Differences between Revisions can be shown Inline or As Code]

However, these do not work the same way with my custom types.

After my custom type, Photo, set as Automatic Versioning:

[image: Custom Type - Photo (to be created within Temple Type) is changed to Automatic Versioning]

its History view lists only revisions, but these not comparable:

[image: Photo history view]

I can see each Revision Preview:

[image: Photo revision previews]

but see no changes between the selected revisions.

[image: No Changes between the Selected Revisions?]

How can I make custom types fully working with CMFEditions?

Comment: is your "photo" type folderish and are you using annotationsotrage for your fields? if yes, then this bug is causing the diff-view not to work proplery: https://dev.plone.org/ticket/11887

Comment: Thanks for the helpful hint. My Photo type is not folderish, but addable only within Temple type that is folderish. I do see this bug with my Temple type (screenshot at https://picasaweb.google.com/114833061013932542407/Plone#5766025544868751810 ) Anyway, all fields of my custom types are using AnnotationStorage. Should I change them to AttributeStorage? How can I preserve old revision info and have the diff-view working?